# Unable to navigate to a website which doesn't allows https certificates

Tags: cypress

I am trying to navigate to a website(it's a centOS machine) which doesn't allows https certificates but unable to.

I tried adding below code to cypress.json:

`"chromeWebSecurity": false`

This didn't help.

Comment: Can you please add the error when you visit your website? And chromeWebSecurity option is not for https certificate but for same origin policy check.

Comment: I get this error message:This site can’t provide a secure connection.
<url of test machine> uses an unsupported protocol.
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Answer (score 0):

This is a know issue waiting to be released.

You can get more info [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/771).

> The code for this is done in cypress-io/cypress#4947, but has yet to
>   be released. We'll update this issue and reference the changelog when
>   it's released.